# How to fix "error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)" in a class of Listener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I can make an `Intent` to open other `Activity` with writing the code in `MainActivity.java`.
Then I try to make an `Intent` using a class and called it in `MainActivity.java`. But it becomes error.
How to solve this problem?

When I write `startActivity(numberIntent);` in `MainActivity.java` there is no error but when I move this line of code to `NumbersClickListener.java`

Errors come:

> 1. error: cannot find symbol method `startActivity(Intent)`
> 2. error: not an enclosing class: `MainActivity`

This my code
In MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.*****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NumbersClickListener clickListener = new NumbersClickListener();

    TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);

    numbers.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

in NumbersClickListener.java

```
package com.example.android.*****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
android.widget.Toast first
import android.widget.Toast;

OnClickListener should be written in capital letter
public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {//.makeText(view.getContext(),
    "open the list of numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent numberIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(numberIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)” in a class of Listener?

Because if `startActivity(Intent)` is a method of activity and its required call from context

If  you want call `startActivity(Intent)` outside activity you need to use 
`Context.startActivity(numberIntent);`

**Use this**

```
view.getContext().startActivity(numberIntent);
```

**instead of this**

```
startActivity(numberIntent);
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent numberIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                NumbersActivity.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(numberIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It solve one error (number one) but hasn't solved the second problem.
1. error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent) 
2. error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity

Comment: @NicholasBiantoro Check my answer. It will handle not an enclosing class error

Answer (score 0):

In place MainActivity.this, use its context.

```
Intent numberIntent = new Intent(context, NumbersActivity.class);
startActivity(numberIntent);
```

Notice the changes I have made

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.*****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NumbersClickListener clickListener = new NumbersClickListener(MainActivity.this);   // Context while creating ClickListener Object

    TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);

    numbers.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

NumbersClickListener.java

```
package com.example.android.*****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
Context context; 
NumbersClickListener(Context c){
    this.context = c;
} 
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent numberIntent = new Intent(context, NumbersActivity.class);
startActivity(numberIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining NumbersClickListener in a separate java file. It has no way compiler will know that when u call startActivity you are referring to the Activity.startActivity

Unless you have a deeper purpose for NumbersClickListener.java, simply do inline declaration of View.Listener will do

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

NumbersClickListener clickListener = new NumbersClickListener();

TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);

numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent numberIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(numberIntent);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To startActivity you need Context.

It will be like this `context.startActivity()`
In MainActivity it is not giving error because Activity internally extends Context.
NumbersClickListener is not extended Context.

So, you can start activity using View context

Replace `startActivity(numberIntent)` with

```
view.getContext().startActivity(numberIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your NumberClickListener class you can do the following
`Context context = view.getContext();
Intent numberIntent = new Intent (context, NumberActivity.class);
context.startActivity(numberIntent);`

By using this code you can use your NumberClickListener with any other activity.
happy codding :)